# View Models staying in memory SwiftUI and Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, memory-management

I am using an MVVM architecture in part of my app that is linked to Firestore Database. A list of players is what I am bringing into my app. The issue is I am creating lots of instances of the PlayerViewModel and they are all staying in memory causing usages of up to 8GB and 1 million instances at some point and I have no idea why.

I bring in the player list through a repository:

```
class PlayerRepository: ObservableObject{
    
    static let shared = PlayerRepository()
    
    var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var players = [DBPlayer]()
    
    @Published var chosenPlayer: DBPlayer? = nil
    
    func loadData(teamID: String){
        
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
        self.players = []
        
        db.collection("players")
            .order(by: "name")
            .whereField("userID", isEqualTo: userID!)
            .whereField("teamID", isEqualTo: teamID)
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot{
                self.players = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                    do{
                        let x = try document.data(as: DBPlayer.self)
                        return x
                    }
                    catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
                    return nil
                    
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Each of these players found are put into the data structure DBPlayer:

```
struct DBPlayer: Identifiable, Equatable, Codable{
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var userID: String?
    var teamID: String
    var name: String
    
    var matchesPlayed: Int = 0
    var secondsPlayed: Int  = 0
    var totalTries: Int = 0
    var totalConversions: Int = 0
    var totalPenaltyKicks: Int = 0
    var totalDropGoals: Int = 0
    var totalPenaltiesConc: Int = 0
    var totalFreeKicksConc: Int = 0
    
    static func ==(lhs: DBPlayer, rhs: DBPlayer) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

I also use a PlayerListViewModel and PlayerViewModel which can be found below:

```
class PlayerListViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var playerRepository = PlayerRepository.shared
    @Published var playerViewModels = [PlayerViewModel]()
    
    private var playerCancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(){
        playerRepository.$players.map { players in
            players.map { player in
                PlayerViewModel(player: player)
            }
        }
        .assign(to: \.playerViewModels, on: self)
        .store(in: &playerCancellables)
        
    }
    
}

class PlayerViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable{
    
    @Published var playerRepository = PlayerRepository.shared
    @Published var player: DBPlayer
    
    var id = ""
    @Published var playerName = ""
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(player: DBPlayer){
        self.player = player
        
        $player
            .map{ player in
                player.name
            }
            .assign(to: \.playerName, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        $player
            .map { player in
                (player.id ?? "")
            }
            .assign(to: \.id, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        $player
            .dropFirst()
            .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { player in
                self.playerRepository.updatePlayer(player)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
    }
    
}
```

I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to memory management but I think that I need to use weak at some point but I do not know where. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's quite a bit of code; a quick review of this  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help. So it's clear you're loading all of the players from Firestore into `self.players` and have a matching number in `playerViewModels`? Your question states *lots of instances of the PlayerViewModel and they are all staying in memory* which is correct as that what the code in the question does. How many players are in memory... millions? Also, in the `PlayerViewModel`, why use `.map` when you only have a single player within that class?

Comment: Also, when there's an object stored as a property of another object, you have access to the child objects properties directly. If you want the player name from a playerView model  `let name = myPlayerViewModel.player.name` will return the players name, and player is already @Published.